# Converting anything to a boolean in Ruby

Tags: ruby, casting, boolean

Playing around in irb, I've noticed you can cast anything to a boolean in Ruby, for example:

```
2.0.0-p451 :021 > !nil
 => true

2.0.0-p451 :024 > !!3
 => true
```

So in effect, `!!` resolves anything to its boolean value. Is there any cleaner way to do this? Without using the `!` operator.

Comment: No, there's no cleaner way to do this. But usually, you don't really need this.

Comment: @MarekLipka it depends on what do we call “cleaner” http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/TrueClass.html#method-i-26

Comment: @mudasobwa you're right. It's also nice. :)

Comment: You can use `!` _method_: `nil.!` or `3.!.!`. :3

Comment: @cremno he did: `!nil` is just syntax for `nil.!`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `!!` is the cleanest way.

If you're on Rails however, you could check out `object.present?`. It returns `false` for all of the following:

```
false
nil
""
[]
{}
```

The last three return `true` with `!!` but will return `false` with `present?`.